# Preventing your device from vibrating whenever it gains or loses its mobile network connection

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, vibration, motorola-moto-g2, voicemail

I've been using a Moto G (2nd generation) running Android 6.0 "Marshmallow".  I was playing with the settings, and changed some setting.  Now, every time the phone loses or regains cellular service — for example, when I'm in the basement, or when I enable or disable airplane mode — the phone vibrates two or three times.  The vibration is noisy and annoying.  What can I do to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a relevant [CrackBerry.com forum post](https://forums.crackberry.com/blackberry-keyone-f445/annoying-alerts-vibration-when-signal-drops-how-do-i-stop-1116810/#post13148549) by Kathy Mansfield.  The post guided me towards a solution that works.

- Open the Phone app.
- Press the three-dots icon in the top-right-hand corner of the app.
- Tap "Settings".
- Tap "Calls".
- Tap "Voicemail".
- Uncheck the "Vibrate" option.

The forum poster explains:

> If you have a pending notification, like a voicemail message you've not retrieved, you'll see the icon for the message. Every time your service is lost and regained, it will vibrate because of the voicemail notification. I suppose it thinks the notification is new. ...
>
> Alternatively, you could just clear the ... voicemail message and hence the notification.